# How to restore MySQL database from WAMP?

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

Last month I had to reinstall Windows and I've moved the [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) folder to another partition. Now I've installed WAMP again but I need the old database. How can I take the old MySQL database from the saved WAMP folder on the safe partion?

In the wamp/bin/mysql/../data/ I have my old databases. If I copy the database folder only, in [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) I can't see all the tables/views from the old database.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you use [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB) tables, so you should also copy ib* files in data folder (but this will overwrite any InnoDB table created in new installation.)

Alternatively (even better) you may set 'datadir' parameter in configuration file and specify path to data folder in old installation.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing changes to MySQL server at the back side (i.e. not using standard MySQL commands or interfaces), remember to stop the server before any changes and start after doing the changes.

Anyway this is not the recommended practice, use `mysqldump` instead to take regular backups and you can later restore a dump file using `mysql ... < dump-file.sql`.

Comment: +1 for stating the obvious, i.e. restart the server (was what I forgot to do) :)

Answer (score 1):

Goto old wamp like wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data folder and copy all content and paste or replace with new setup folder "wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data".