# Backup DB from MYSQL command prompt

Tags: mysql, command-line, wamp, database-backups

I recently tried to put my web application and mysql database on the same virtual server. Now I receive a port error. In order to fix the port issue, I want to back up the database and reinstall WAMP. Since I can't get to the phymyadmin, I have to use the mysql command prompt to do a dump.

Would anyone happen to know the EXACT command to put in, if my username is root, I have no password, and the database name is dev? I've tried it multiple ways and I get an error saying that my syntax is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command provided you know the name of the database:

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

Alternatively I would install the MySQL Workbench which can connect to your local database instance and provides a GUI to run the export: [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Unfortunately if you've uninstalled WAMP then MySQL might not be running anymore, and the above commands will not work because the utilities cannot see the database. If this is the case, try installing WAMP to a new directory and manually copying over the MySQL data files:

[How to restore MySQL database from WAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082473/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-wamp)

Comment: MySQL Workbench worked great. The command lacks a good interface and instruction. When I entered the command, nothing happened. No error, and no creation of a dump file. GUI all the way.

Comment: Glad that worked for you! No better GUI tool for working with MySQL imo.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqldump -u root -p dev > devBackUp.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

DOS batch file to export the database with date and time in the filename

```
FOR /f "tokens=1-8 delims=:./ " %%G IN ("%date%_%time%") DO (
SET dt=%%G%%H%%I_%%J_%%K
)
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name]> [database_name]_%dt%.sql
pause
```